# How to update data in Firestore Database

Tags: c#, firebase

In the picture there is my firebase database in firestore.
[image]

I have a problem updating my variable "added", it is bool. I want to change this bool from true to false etc. and I do not want other data to change.

I found code like this:

> ```
>         DocumentReference docref = db.Collection("Notes").Document(notes[a].id);
>         Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
>         {
>             { "added","true"},
>             { "createDate",notes[a].createDate.ToString()},
>             { "id",notes[a].id.ToString()},
>             { "localisation",notes[a].localisation.ToString()},
>             { "notes",notes[a].notes.ToString()},
>             { "title",notes[a].title.ToString()},
>             { "uid",notes[a].uid.ToString()},
>         };
>         DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();
>         if (snap.Exists)
>         {
>             await docref.SetAsync(data);
>         }
> ```

but this code deletes everything, and changes all my data to string, createDate I want to stay in "DateTime", and added as a "bool". How to do that?

Just saying that I did connected to my database, and I do have access to my id, from which I can find my item in collection "Notes"

UPDATE:
code:

```
DocumentReference docref = db.Collection("Notes").Document(notes[a].id);
            Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "added","true"},
            };
            DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();
            if (snap.Exists)
            {
                await docref.UpdateAsync(data);
            }
```

also do not work, it changes my "added" in firebase from bool to string, I do not want that

Comment: Did you see the documentation on updating data?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Comment: I did tried with "UpdateAsync", but up there I still have dictionary, and this dictionary is <string, object>...{ "added","true"}, and ok, I need only one thing to update it, but it convers my variable to string, I need it to stay bool, when I change dictionary I get errors, I do not know how to change dictionary

Comment: oh, I changed "{ "added","true"}," to "{ "added",true}," and I have a bool, everything works, thx!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my problem whas to use "UpdateAsync" and write true as a bool, not string, my code:

```
    DocumentReference docref = db.Collection("Notes").Document(notes[a].id);
    Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "added",true},
    };
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();
    if (snap.Exists)
    {
        await docref.UpdateAsync(data);
    }
```

this code allows me to update one element, and not change it to string

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DocumentReference docref = db.Collection(Notes).Document(notes[a].id);
DocumentSnapshot snap = await docref.GetSnapshotAsync();

if (snap.Exists)
{
   await docref.UpdateAsync("added", true);
}
```